# how to import multiple branch cases structure into LaTeX document.

Tags: cases

Could I set up a structure for several cases so that I could get a TeX command branch say, behavior as below:

---

**if case A**

- if case A1

`\cmdAi{arg1}`

- elseif case A2

`\cmdAii{arg2}`

- elseif case A3

`\cmdAiii{arg3}`

- endif

**elseif case B**

- elseif case B1

`\cmdBi{arg4}`

- elseif case B2

`\cmdBii{arg5}`

- end if

**endif**

---

the case A1~case B2 is given in advance, say, from the ordered collection (maybe its form is `{\`a,\'a,\^a,`A,\^A}`).

I knew the `ifthen` package, but it is too simple (or to complicated?) to use conveniently.

A intuitive explain:

this demand is related to the modal logic and semantics. Think about  a given alphabetic chain of *n* bit (n less than 16), say,

```
TxFxyxxTyxTFyT

zTyxTzzxxTyxF
```

etc. The character `T` denoted "True" or constant have value 1, the character `F` denoted "False" or constant have value 0, the other character `x`, `y`, `z`, and so on denoted variables whose value between 0 and 1 (not have to equal). After we assigned for the variables, I want to print the result like:

> the chain given above has valuables [#1] (@1) times (or print which places has [#1] appeared in), [#2] (@2) times, [#3] (@3) times, ... and their weight sum is ...

the [#1], [#2], [#3], etc. is the `x`, `y`, `z`, respectively; the (@1), (@2), (@3), , etc. mean as former.

Comment: It may help if you give us some more idea of the purpose of this.  Also, what is it about the `ifthen` package that is inconvenient?

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help to learn how to format posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure as to what you are after, but since you mentioned ordered lists here is an approach. One of the difficulties of using "TeX" as a computer language is its lack of built-in datastructures. But once you have lists, you can built any type of datastructure you wish and I think that is what you need here. However, some shift from common programming paradigms is necessary, so here is a traditional TeX solution.

Consider the following list of keywords in a list:

```
\def\alist{A--,A+,A++,A-,A=,A==,}
```

and for which the ordered list is, `A+,A++,A--,A---,A=,A==,`

Each element in the list will act as an "object" and hold some information, being a `true`, `false` or anything else you may wish.

We define a suitable macro to add an element and its definition to the list and we order the list.

```
\def\AddElementToList#1#2#3{%
  \lst@lAddTo#1{#2,}
  \expandafter\def\csname#2\endcsname{#3}
  \lst@BubbleSort{\alist}
}
```

We can loop the list and expand the meaning of all the elements using the `@for` command from the LaTeX kernel.

```
\@for \i:=\alist \do{%
  \texttt{%
  \expandafter\csname\i\endcsname}\par    
}
```

Any individual element can be accessed by its name as `\@nameuse{A==}`.

As you can see from the commands you can store any type of `object` in the list. It can be a single digit or provided you define your macros accordingly can hold a full chapter of a book or possibly the book itself!. One caveat with the MWE shown below, if you writing in turkish change the `\i` to something else or run the code within a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstdoc}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
%% define a list for demo purposes
\def\alist{A--,A+,A++,A-,A=,A==,}
%% typeset the unsorted list
\texttt\alist

The ordered list
%% the sorted list
\lst@BubbleSort{\alist}
\texttt\alist

%% empty the list
\let\alist\empty
%% add element and define the element macro
\def\AddElementToList#1#2#3{%
  \lst@lAddTo#1{#2,}
  \expandafter\def\csname#2\endcsname{#3}
  \lst@BubbleSort{\alist}
}

%Consider adding some elements
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A+}{True}
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A++}{False}
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A-}{False}
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A=}{0}
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A==}{1}
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A--}{1}
\AddElementToList{\alist}{A---}{$a^2+33=f_2$}

\texttt\alist

%% loop over the list
\@for \i:=\alist \do{%
  \texttt{%
  \expandafter\csname\i\endcsname}\par    
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

You can consider that the `alist` is your `case` statement.

Comment: @Y.L. I'am reading, though that's a bit diffcult to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stufazi Hoqckt If you edit your post to define the problem a bit more clearly, I can edit the post to make it more specific. Start perhaps from a scan saying, I want to achieve this...